# asp.net Pass dictionary as additional parameter in ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, dictionary

I need to send a key-value pair of values to a webmethod in aspx page.

Thats why i created a dictionary in javascript file like this:

```
var parentSelects = $('select[datacolumnname]');
            var parentValues = [];
            for (index = 0; index < parentSelects.length; ++index) {
                var select = $(parentSelects[index]);
                var keyToPush = select.attr("datacolumnname");
                var valueToPush = select.val();
                parentValues.push({
                    key: keyToPush,
                    value: valueToPush
                });
            }
```

In my aspx file there is a webmethod like this

```
Public Shared Function LoadChildData(ByVal parentId As String, ByVal parentValue As String, ByVal childId As String, ByVal childValue As String, ByVal dictionary As Dictionary(Of String,String)) As String
{
   // I NEED TO GET DICTIONARY VALUES HERE
}
```

I create data to send like this:

```
 var mydata = "{'parentId':" + parentId + ", 'parentValue': '" + $(this).val() + "', 'childId': '" + childs[i] + "', 'childValue': '" + childValue + "'" + ", 'dictionary': '" + JSON.stringify(parentValues) + "'}";

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: myurl,
                    data: mydata,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (rdata) {
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
```

I couldnt able to send dictionary as parameter, ajax method alerts "Error".

How can i send dictionary as parameter for webmethod in aspx ?

Comment: "it always throws error" Please elaborate. What error? Is it thrown by the JavaScript or ASP.NET code?

Comment: It goes to ajax method's error. I mean it alerts "Error" .